# How many limit points does $\sin^2(\pi n/2)+(-1)^n/{\pi n} $ have?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

How many limit points does $S_n = \sin^2(\pi n/2)+(-1)^n/{\pi n}$ have?

I think it has only one limit point, but I'm not so sure since  I'm confused by the definition of limit points I see online (they use topology?). I'd appreciate if someone could show me how to do this.

It seems to me since $\sin^2(\pi n/2) = 1$ that we $\displaystyle S_n = 1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\pi n}.$

So  $\displaystyle S_{2n} = 1+\frac{1}{2\pi n} \to 1$ and $\displaystyle S_{2n+1} = 1-\frac{1}{\pi(2n+1)} \to 1$

So no subsequence of $S_n$ converges anything other than $1$?

Comment: Why do you think that $sin^2(\pi n / 2) \rightarrow 1$ ?

Comment: @MichaelStocker Oh, sometimes it's zero! Thanks.

Comment: Yep, you did a bit of miscalculation for the even numbered subsequence.

Comment: @EvanWilliamChandra Thanks. Can I say, the following, without considering subsequences? $1-\frac{1}{n \pi} \le S_n \le 1+\frac{1}{n \pi}$ so $S_n  \to 1$ by the squeeze theorem. Therefore the sequence has exactly one limit point?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't because you have to show that $1- \frac{1}{n\pi}$ is the lower bound of $S_{n}$. Try to see why it is not the lower bound, for example, take $n=2$ and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the case when $n=2k$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Observe that we have
$$S_{2k} = (\sin(k\pi))^{2}+\frac{1}{2\pi k}= \frac{1}{2\pi k}$$. Hence the limit to infinity is zero.

Clearly the subsequence $S_{2k}$ and $S_{2k+1}$ do not have the same limit value as $k$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you mind saying something about the condition for a sequence to have multiple limit points, one limit point, or zero limit points? Because I'm sort of winging it right now. All online sources seem to be using language of topology I'm not familiar with!

Comment: Your question (for me at least) seems to be hard to answer because it really depends on what kind of sequence you have and in what kind of metric space. However, "naively speaking", you can say that a sequence has "unique" limit point when it converges. On the other hand, a divergence sequence can either have "multiple limit points" or simply be unbounded.

Comment: Many thanks again! You have been very helpful!